# How to do Reactstrap Input Select dropdown customization

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, reactstrap

I'm trying to customize Reactstrap Input Select Dropdown as shown below. I just want to remove the border and add some shadow,change the color of "Option" hover effect. Tries to override the Select class, But no luck. Any help.

```
    <FormGroup>
      <Label for="exampleSelect">Select</Label>
      <Input type="select" name="select" id="exampleSelect">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </Input>
    </FormGroup>
```

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the below design.

[image]